# Multiplos valores de consulta com JPA/Sprint e Rest

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-jpa

Bom dia, preciso fazer uma consulta via REST onde serão enviados múltiplos ID por exemplo(ID: 1, ID: 2, ID:3, etc). 
Para buscar somente por um ID eu uso `findById(codigo)`, porém não sei como fazer para utilizar múltiplos dados.
Como estou utilizando RESTFull, como ficaria a URI separada por múltiplos dados?
Como ficaria meu recurso?
Hoje eu faço assim(para um ID)

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<OBJ> buscarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable Long codigo) {
   Optional<OBj> obj = pessoaRepository.findById(codigo);
   return obj.isPresent() ? ResponseEntity.ok(obj.get()) : ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
}
```

e a URI:
localhost:8080/dados/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode enviar um array de ids por parametro, por ex:

supondo que sua 
**URL RAIZ** é localhost:8080/dados/

no seu método getMapping fica assim: `@GetMapping("/{ids}")`

e o corpo do método:

```
public ResponseEntity<OBJ> buscarPeloCodigo(@PathVariable Long[] ids) {
    //aqui é só iterar o array
}
```

repare que agora você recebe um array do tipo long.

e por fim a **chamada** no front end:

```
localhost:8080/dados/1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é que você envie um array de códigos por queryString, ai você pode criar um iteração para cada código ou mesmo um método que receba um lista de código e faça um select nesses critérios.

```
// recurso
@GetMapping("/")
public ResponseEntity<List<OBJ>> buscarPessoasPorCodigos(@RequestParam(value="codigos") List<Long> codigos) {
           List<OBJ> objList = findAllById(codigos);
           return objList.isEmpty() ? ResponseEntity.notFound().build() : ResponseEntity.ok(objList));
        }
```

// repository

```
List<OBJ> findAllById(Iterable<Long> ids);
```

// url exemplo

```
http://localhost:8080/api/pessoas?codigos=1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: Perfeito meu caro, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Minha proposta e fazer um bom tratamento para usar um ExceptionHandler

```
@RestController
@ControllerAdvice
class Controller {

    @GetMapping(value = "list")
    public List<Object> buscarPorCodigo(@RequestParam Integer[] codigo) {
        return pessoaRepository.findById(codigo);
        /*se não for encontrado nenhuma pessoa basta dar throw
       EntityNotFoundException que vai cair no handlerEntityNotFound*/
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    ResponseEntity<String> handlerEntityNotFound(EntityNotFoundException ex, WebRequest web) {
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

chamada fica `localhost:8080/list?codigo=1?codigo=2?codigo=3`